MUI Table unable to display img or icon in table cell
I am trying to display an icon in a cell of a simple Mui Table.
<Table>
    <TableHead>
        <TableRow>
          <TableCell> Name </TableCell>
          <TableCell> Icon </TableCell>
        </TableRow>
    </TableHead>
    <TableBody>
        <TableRow>
            <TableCell>
                Alice
            </TableCell>
            <TableCell>
                <RiInformationFill />    {/* or <img src="some image">  // does not work */}
            </TableCell>
        </TableRow>
    </TableBody>
</Table>

No matter what I try the Icon or image does not show. However on inspection the element is indeed there, just not visible.

And in the network pane in dev tools, is the image HTTP req successful? If so, this sounds like a CSS issue. Try inspecting the img tag and go to the "computed" styles pane. What is its width and height? Is it falling outside a container with overflow: hidden maybe?
